# Statistics Interview Question

Tags: probability, distributions, poisson-distribution, gamma-distribution

**Imagine you are solving difficult Math problems and you expect to solve one every 1/2 hour. Compute the probability that you will have to wait between 2 to 4 hours before you solve four of them.**

I came across two solutions for this.

**1st Solution:**

Let X be the number of 1/2-hour intervals we have to wait before we solve one theorem. Then X follows a Poisson distribution with parameter λ = 1/2, because we expect to solve one theorem every 1/2 hour.

We want to find the probability that we will have to wait between 2 to 4 hours before we solve four theorems. Let Y be the total number of 1/2-hour intervals we have to wait before we solve four theorems. Then Y follows a Poisson distribution with parameter μ = 4/λ = 8.

We want to find P(8 ≤ Y ≤ 16), which is the probability that we will have to wait between 2 to 4 hours (i.e., between 8 and 16 1/2-hour intervals) before we solve four theorems. We can calculate this probability using the cumulative distribution function (CDF) of the Poisson distribution:

P(8 ≤ Y ≤ 16) = F(16; 8) - F(8; 8) = ~9%

**2nd Solution :**

Gamma distribution arises naturally in which the waiting time between Poisson distributed events are relevant to each other. One theorem every 1/2 hour means we would suppose to get θ = 1 / 0.5 = 2 theorem every hour on average. Using θ = 2 and k = 4, Now we can calculate it as follows: f(x) = x^k e^(-x)/ G(k) where G is the Gamma function. Plugging in the values we get ~ 12%

I think the 1st solution is correct and not the second one. What are your thoughts?

Comment: The question should be modified to make it explicit that the time to solve a problem is exponentially distributed.

Comment: In your Poisson approach, "2 to 4 hours" should equal to "4 to 8 half-hours" (instead of "8 to 16 half-hours")